# How to recover schema of SQL server tables I lost because of full restore?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I mistakenly restored a database on my local SQL server (12.0). I did a full restore. But I lost schema of tables I had created recently on my local SQL database. Is there any way to recover this table schema?

Thanks for help.

Comment: This wont help you now, but im sure next time you wont forget to backup first... I dont think it is possible what you want

Comment: If this is a production environment ask your storage team if they have a snapshot of the LUN or what ever other storage it's sitting on. But generally speaking, @GuidoG is right

Comment: I'm confused. If you restored your database and all the tables, data, keys, constraints, etc. came back, what exactly are you missing? Are you talking about the actual database diagram that you can create in Enterprise Manager?

Comment: @TerryCarmen the backup was out of date

Comment: @Larnu OK. Sorry.  If you work for a large organization, whoever maintains your servers might have incremental snapshots they could restore. Otherwise you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: Also, there's no reason not to source control your database schema in this day and age. If you don't like Microsoft's Database projects, there are various other tools from e.g. Redgate that also support this idea.

Comment: Redgate's "Tab History" editor feature is also a nice backup - it's saved my bacon from things like this on numerous occasions, including yesterday where I was able to recover 2 months of stored procedure coding that had been overwritten by someone else restoring a database in our test environment.  But that doesn't help you right now, Malay.  If there's no backup of your local server, you're out of luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and taking time. I will be extra careful from now on. I will put my DB in source control.